# PWA's Project Center Timeline Not Adding Tasks or Projects After Editing Webpart

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, timeline, project-server

My organization uses Project Web App integrated with Sharepoint task lists to share project plans and delivery schedules.  Project Web App's Project Center has an aggregate timeline feature, which allows you to add tasks from individual PWA sites to a portfolio-wide timeline.  This timeline is a fairly standard Sharepoint web part.

After editing the height of the timeline web part on the Project Center page (I wanted this to have a fixed px value...), I realized all of my previously added tasks and projects had disappeared from the timeline.  Now, after I attempt to re-add a task or project, nothing actually appears on the timeline.

I've since reverted my changes to the height and rechecked all of the web app properties, but to no avail.  I even tried creating a new Timeline web app-- no dice.  Microsoft Support has been of no help--- even escalating to a PWA/Project Online/Project Pro specialist has warranted no fixes.

What can I do to bring back my timeline's Add Task functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I was disappointed with PWA's timeline functionality because it wouldn't match my project's timeline. Some callout tasks would be misplaced and overlap each other in PWA while everything looked good in the MS Project 2013 file. The text color in the bars would always be black, regardless of what it was in the Project file.

As a workaround, I took a screenshot of the timeline in the MS Project file and saved it as an image. I created a webpart in PWA for rich text (html) and inserted the image (my timeline).

It will be hard to address your issue directly because your enterprise will have unique functionality in it and not even Microsoft is willing (or able) to help you =/

Answer (score 0):

When you Edit the Page, you have to make sure the type in the webpart properties is set to 'webpart' not to 'list'... just learnt that the hard way :-)